# How to implement IP filter on 2 billion IP addresses?

Tags: node.js, network-programming

We have different projects and one of them is [white label DSP solution](https://smartyads.com/white-label-solution) . 
Our client requested to enable the filtering of all incoming traffic by IP. 
They gave us the list of addresses which contains **2.05 billion** records and it should work in real-time.

These addresses can be compacted into 6 million ranges. We have only **10 milliseconds** to conduct this check-up.

This task should be implemented using **NodeJS**.

Do you have any suggestion on how to get it done or which mechanism should be appropriate for this task?

Comment: Are those addresses likely or unlikely hits? Regardless of how you ultimately look them up, a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) could help reduce demands on the lookup.

Comment: If they're IPV4 addresses, than you're excluding more than half of the total address space. So it may well be easier to whitelist addresses that aren't on the list, rather than blacklisting addresses that are. How many ranges can you compact the _unblocked_ addresses into?

Answer (score 1):

It must be easy to load already sorted IPs to that kind of structure. Just walk down through your billions and fill:

```
{
    100: {
        150: {
            200: [250, 251],
            205: [250]
        }
    },
    105: {
        110: {
            115: [120]
        },
        115: {
            150: [200]
        }
    }
}
```

Then just check the key presence for each octet of an IP that must be filtered.
JavaScript optimizes integer-dictionaries and uses the binary search on them.
I don't know if there is unsigned byte in NodeJS, or you need tens of gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: Good idea, very bad explanation. Please add some more details

Comment: I think it is summarized to what hedgar mentioned. What details are missing @Jesse ? I could help

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you mean by 'all incoming traffic'. If you're filtering IP packets and you need a scalable solution, I would strongly suggest against it. There is some SDN hardware that could be used to do what they want but I guess that's outside of the project's scope.

Anyway, I'll try to answer your question (at least partially) and give you some general tips (not node.js specific). First, there are a few things that should be clarified and those are:

1. Are we talking only about IPv4?
2. Is the list dynamic (will they 
   add/remove IPs from the list)

Regardless, you can apply the similar that routers do when they're doing route lookups. You can build patricia trie ([Radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)) and do the search in it (Also take a look at [this](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/vst.pdf) article if you're serious about it). Keep in mind that in routing world 10ms is considered to be a lifetime so even the software based router on a 'slow' speed CPU (under 1GHz) could possibly do hundreds of IPv4 lookups in 10ms timeframe. hedgar2017 gave you similar example and depending on how much resources you have (and how much traffic), you probably don't need to worry about performance (if you're checking the IP only when establishing a user session).

If you're also doing IPv6 (and you should at least plan for it) the approach is similar. Only thing i would mention is that even if IPv6 has 128bits, ISPs are assigning each user a /48 (or in the worst case scenario /64) prefix. You can build your tree up to /48 and get a bit faster lookups.